# How to fetch logs (AWS VPC LOGS) from aws which are seen on cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3, logstash, aws-sdk

How do I fetch logs (AWS VPC LOGS) from aws which are seen on cloudwatch? I am confused between which API to use. The cloud watch api is about fetching the metrics and not about getting the log events.

If someone could help me getting a Java example to fetch logs into a file. I want to append the logs to a file. I have my own logging infrastructure for which I am using logstash-statsD-graphite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the AWSLogs client, in the package com.amazonaws.services.logs : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogs.html

You have the GetLogEventsRequest object to perform the request, and everything you need to paginate. You'll get a list of OutputLogEvent with timestamps and messages (and as far as I know, each message should be a VPC flow record).

The full API doc is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Hope this will get you started

Comment: Thanks but I preferred using AWS CLI in logstash. It is easy and quick.